# xcode 8.2.1 - how to reset expired free provisioning certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

My iOS provisioning certificate expired.  I got a message saying I needed to renew it.  I've tried:

- Logging in to developer.apple.com.  There is nothing on this site that helps, because every option just tells me I need to pay £79 for a developer program membership.
- Looking at the xcode provisioning settings for my project. They say:

> Status: Your session has expired.  Please log in.
>
> No profiles for [my app bundle id]  were found

- Logging in again with my Apple ID.  I chose "add an account..." from the "Team" dropdown box, and then try signining in with my Apple ID.  I get an error saying "Account already exists. This account has already been added."
- Removing my Apple ID and signing in again.  This did not change anything.
- Signing up for a new Apple ID.  I clicked the "sign up" button under the xcode login dialog, but on the "get started with your name, email address and password" page, when I press "Next" an error "Unexpected error occurred" appears under the email address field.
- Attempting to build and run my project on a phone, which at least one answer to a similar question suggested would cause xcode to correct the problem itself.  It didn't -- I get an error that reads "An unknown error occurred. An unknown error occurred."

So... how do I get my project building again now my provisioning profile has expired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problems were resolved by restarting xcode, other than the latter which required unplugging and reconnecting the phone.  Not sure what the problem was, but it was clearly temporary.

Comment: @Zotyi - good point.  Keep forgetting to accept my self-answers. :)